# ID of ResourcePool

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to keep track of the resource used in a specific action?
Let me explain better: I have a resourcePool composed of three classrooms, each agent that enters the flow occupies one of the three classrooms for a specific time. Can I track the classroom used by the agent?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The [Seize](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/seize.html) block has a 'on seize unit' event where you get access to both the agent seizing the unit and the unit itself, so it is possible to make a record somewhere of which unit is being seized. Or, alternatively, you can call `resourceUnits()` method on any agent to get a list of resource units it is currently holding. Please see more here in [Agent API help](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/javadoc/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html).

Comment: But is it possible to specifically choose a resource from a resourcePool?
Let me explain: my model is that of a hospital! when a patient is visited by a doctor who is part of a ResourcePool, is it possible to indicate that the second visit is made by exactly the same doctor?

Comment: There are 2 ways to do that: **Seize** has `Customize resource choice` option and **ResourcePool** has `Request choice condition`. To achieve the 'follow-up' functionality the original choice of resource have to be recorded somehow and then checked when the patient agent attempts to seize a doctor again.